# virus problem in home page

Tags: php, html, malware

i have recently maked a site which if i open that in chrome it gives me a malware protection error and if i open it in ff or ie it gives me to install Java plugin, but i haven't add any java applet to home page and not any maleware or trojan on home page why it is showing it to me......

please let me know how can i check my html code for virus or iframes for viruses

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check your HTML code for suspicious `<script>` and `<iframe>` blocks. If you find any, they could have been added by a virus on your computer or by someone who sniffed your FTP password and changed the files on the FTP server.

Answer (score 2):

It might be you did not properly sanitize input you output and someone exploited this to inject malicious code to your site. This could be through URL params or forms for example or when including content from other servers, like ad rotation banners.

See

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csrf